# how should i get best captcha plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

this type of captcha is available in wordpress?[image]

i had seen many captcha plugin but i dont get this type of  captcha

Answer (score 1):

Actually that exact plugin exists for Wordpress:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-recaptcha/